# How to access a string value from the fragment to the main activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an android application in which I used `webview` fragment. From that fragment, i am going to take the current url by using the below code. But the problem is that I want to access `String webUrl` from the MainActivity.

How can I get it? What I actually planned to do is creating a favorite url according to the wish of the user from the fragment.

```
final String webUrl = view.getUrl();
```

Comment: you can make that string static/ use sharedpreference or use custom Listener Interface

Comment: can you show me the code/example to that ? @DivyeshPatel

Comment: just follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android) tutorial. This should help

Comment: that is activity to the fragment rgt?, i want fragment to activity@RodKimble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Interface :

```
public interface HomeListener {

    void onHomeClick(String url);
}
```

Now in Fragment:

```
HomeListener mCallback;

 @Override
    public void onAttach(Context con) {
        super.onAttach(con);
        try {
            mCallback = (HomeListener) con;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        mCallback = null;
        super.onDetach();
    }
```

Now when url is get:

```
mCallback.onHomeClick(view.getUrl());
```

Last in Activity, implement HomeListener, and override method:

```
@Override
    public void onHomeClick(String url) {

       Log.e("urlFromFragment",url);


}
```

Sample Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements HomeListener {

        String URL="";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        }


        @Override
    public void onHomeClick(String url) {

           URL=url;
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), URL, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143380/discussion-on-answer-by-divyesh-patel-how-to-access-a-string-value-from-the-frag).

Comment: check above answer.

Comment: one last thing , when it will take the url from webview ??,,

Comment: one last thing , when it will take the url from webview ??,

Comment: everytime  mCallback.onHomeClick(view.getUrl()); method called

Answer (score 1):

From Activity to Fragment:
In your fragment, use `getActivity()` method to access the object of Activity.

```
YourActivity activity = (YourActivity) getActivity();
activity.someString = "some_url";
webView.setUrl(activity.someString);
```

From Fragment to Activity:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
SampleFragment sampleFragment=(SampleFragment)  fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id);
activity.someString = "some_url";
webView.setUrl(activity.someString);
```

Your fragment root view should have the same id:

`SampleFragment.xml` file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_id" >
<!-- [Your other layout views goes here] -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i want get string from fragment to activity not activity to fragment